# Dull with a D -- that's me!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> *Embarking on a lengthy trip will oft begin with me.
>
>   High on majestic mountain tops with snow I'll often be.*
>
> *Your house and home will need my touch when hurricanes are nigh.
>
>   And if it's damaged by the storm, you'll see me stopping by.*
>
> *I might show up without your leave upon the open sea.
>
>   Your penalty in hockey might just be because of me.*
>
> *If you are staying here a while, I'll gladly cook for you.
>
>   And if you have me at your school, I'll sleep there with you, too.*
>
> *Sometimes I like to skate, and I can pull a mean airwalk.
>
>   When I get wet it will be torture getting me to talk.*
>
> *Pray, tell me who I am and who this verse shows me to be.
>
>   Each line is something different, but they all refer to me.*

A successful answer will explain *each* line, as well as the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer..

> BOARDING ("Boring with A D")

Embarking on a lengthy trip will oft begin with me.

> Boarding a ship/plane

High on majestic mountain tops with snow I'll often be.

> Snowboard

Your house and home will need my touch when hurricanes are nigh.

> Board up Windows for protection

And if it's damaged by the storm, you'll see me stopping by.

> Boarding (as in drywalling)

I might show up without your leave upon the open sea.

> Boarding a boat (like pirates)

Your penalty in hockey might just be because of me.

> Boarding in ice hockey is a penalty called when an offending player pushes, trips..

If you are staying here a while, I'll gladly cook for you.

> Boarding house

And if you have me at your school, I'll sleep there with you, too.

> Boarding school

Sometimes I like to skate, and I can pull a mean airwalk.

> Skateboard

When I get wet it will be torture getting me to talk.

> Waterboarding (torture)

Comment: +1 Looks like the title also fits. Hint: take away the 'd'.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE :D

Comment: Bore, noun: "A person whose talk or behaviour is dull"

Answer (score 3):

You are a...

> DOG!

Embarking on a lengthy trip will oft begin with me.

> Em"bark"ing

High on majestic mountain tops with snow I'll often be.

> Usually, (St. Bernard) dogs are used for help in cold skiing areas

Your house and home will need my touch when hurricanes are nigh.

> You were a hurricane at one point in time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Dog_(1950)

And if it's damaged by the storm, you'll see me stopping by.

> You will call for help if your 'owner' needs your assistance.

I might show up without your leave upon the open sea.

> You sometimes

Your penalty in hockey might just be because of me.

> DOG is shortened as Delay of game, known as a hockey term.

If you are staying here a while, I'll gladly cook for you.

> Don't laugh, it does exist: https://www.youtube.com/user/cookingwithdog

And if you have me at your school, I'll sleep there with you, too.

> You do sleep when in comfy areas

Sometimes I like to skate, and I can pull a mean airwalk.

> to skate or 2 steak? Pull airwalk or pull meanly when walking?

When I get wet it will be torture getting me to talk.

> You like to clean/dry yourself first before getting your owners attention.

Pray, tell me who I am and who this verse shows me to be.
Each line is something different, but they all refer to me.

> You, a dog!

Title:

> Dull with a dog; a dull dog skin is most likely a dog with a skin that does not have enough nutrition

Comment: Valiant effort, but you seem to have missed the [tag:wordplay] tag!  (And some of those answers are quite a stretch...)

Comment: I like dogs and they should be the right answer whenever possible.